# filter result of observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service which returns an observable of organization object, and I want to filter the result based on organizationID I pass.

Currently I am doing something like this, but it returns me all the values instead of filtered one.

```js
filteredOrganization(organizationId: number) {
  return this.http.get < Organization[] > (this.baseUrl + '/list').pipe(
    map(organizations => {
      return organizations.filter(organization => {
        organization.id === organizationId;
        return {
          id: organization.id,
          name: organization.name,
        };
      });
    }),
  );
}
```

For Eg. service returns
[{1: abc, 2: def, 3: pqr}]

What I want
I pass 1 as organization Id and want result [{1: abc}]

What I am getting
[{1: abc, 2: def, 3: pqr}]

Comment: `filter()` expects a boolean to be returned which determines whether an element should be included in the result.

Comment: This line: `organization.id === organizationId;` is a comparison, not an assignment. Did you intend a single `=`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-euxd7m?file=src/app/app.component.ts

filter (rxjs) expects a boolean to be returned and, in this case,
need not specify the return as an object.

You're already making a map, and just filtering...

```
this.appService.get()
     .pipe(
        map(organizations => {
          return organizations.filter(x => x.id === organizationId);
        })
      )
      .subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 3):

The example you are showing you don't need to do map, as the output format is the same as the input. You just need to do filter.

```
filteredOrganization(organizationId: number) {
    return this.http.get<Organization[]>(this.baseUrl + '/list').pipe(
        filter(organization => organization.id === organizationId))
});
```

Comment: @Rishav Are you able to mark the right answer so other people can learn from your question?

Comment: Agreed, this is definitely the most correct way to do it.

Comment: Does this work in rxjs 6+ ? I think you should be using piping

Answer (score 0):

Your `map` function within the `pipe` operator should filter the results by org ID first then `map` the filtered results to the desired form and then return to the subscriber of a stream:

```
filteredOrganization(organizationId: number) {
  return this.http.get < Organization[] > (this.baseUrl + '/list').pipe(
    map(organizations => {
      return organizations.filter((org) => org.id === organizationId).map((org) => {
        return { id: organization.id, name: organization.name};
      });
    }),
  );
}
```

Comment: It's a redundant `map` though.